# Product of two stationary random processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stationary-processes

Let $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ be two stationary random processes and $$Z(t)=X(t)Y(t)$$By stationary I mean stationary in the strict sense which is $$F_{X(t_1),...,X(t_k)}(x_1,...,x_k)=F_{X(t_1+h),...,X(t_k+h)}(x_1,...,x_k)$$for all $h,t_1,...,t_k\in \mathbb{R}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

$1$. Is $Z(t)$ a stationary random process?

$2$. If $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are independent random processes, is $Z(t)$ a stationary random process?

**My try:**

$1$. Intuitively, the answer is no but I couldn't find a counterexample. For example if we set $Y(t) = aX(t)$ then $Z(t) = aX^2(t)$ and it's stationary.

$2$. In this case the answer seems to be yes. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4295616/is-the-product-of-two-strictly-stationary-independent-processes-strictly-stati) post provides an answer but I don't understand why independence implies $$(X_{t_1 + h}, X_{t_2 + h}, \ldots, X_{t_n + h},Y_{t_1 + h}, Y_{t_2 + h}, \ldots, Y_{t_n + h}) \stackrel{d}{=} (X_{t_1 }, X_{t_2 }, \ldots, X_{t_n }, Y_{t_1 }, Y_{t_2 }, \ldots, Y_{t_n }) \tag{1}$$
Also, why $(1)$ implies $(2)$?$$f(X_{t_1 + h}, X_{t_2 + h}, \ldots, X_{t_n + h},Y_{t_1 + h}, Y_{t_2 + h}, \ldots, Y_{t_n + h})\stackrel{d}{=} f(X_{t_1 }, X_{t_2 }, \ldots, X_{t_n }, Y_{t_1 }, Y_{t_2 }, \ldots, Y_{t_n }) \tag{2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding part 1, here is a discrete-time counterexample:

Let $X_k$ be i.i.d. $\pm 1$ valued variables of mean zero, and let $\{W_k\}{k \in \mathbb Z}$ be an independent copy of  $\{X_k\}_{k \in \mathbb Z}$. Define $Y_k=X_k$ for $k$ even and
$Y_k=W_k$ for $k$ odd. Then $\{X_k\}$ is a stationary sequence and so is $\{Y_k\}$. However, $\{Y_kX_k\}_{k \in \mathbb Z}$ is not stationary.

To get a continuous time example, pick $U$ uniform in $[0,1]$ and independent of the previous variables. For real $t$, let $X(t)=X_k$
iff $k \in \mathbb Z$ and  $k-1+U < t \le k+U$. Define $Y(t)$ from $\{Y_k\}$ similarly, with the same $U$.

Regarding part 2:

Equation (1) holds because both the distributions of both sides have the form $\mu \times \nu$ with the same $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Equation (2) holds because we applied the same function to both sides of (1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let say $\mathbb{P}(X\le x,Y\le y) = \mathbb{P}(U\le x,V\le y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Define vector valued function $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)$. Why can function be applied to the both sides of equation? I mean how to prove $$\mathbb{P}(X^2+Y^2\le x , X^2-Y^2\le y) = \mathbb{P}(U^2+V^2\le x , U^2-V^2\le y)$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is better to think in terms of measures, rather than distribution functions. The law of $(X,Y)$ is a measure $\mu$ on the plane, where $\mu(B)=P((X,Y) \in B$. The law of $(U,V)$ is the same measure. The law of $f(X,Y)$ is the push-forward of $\mu$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure. The probability that $f(X,Y) \in A$ for a   Borel set $A$ is the chance that $(X,Y)$ lands in $f^{-1}(A)$, i.e. $\mu(f^{-1}(A))$. The probability that  $f(U,V) \in A$ is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a proof which doesn't require measure theory because the question is asked in an engineering course on random process. Can it proved using the distribution functions? Also is there any condition for function $f$?

Comment: No measure theory needed. You just need to know the definition of a measure. Distribution functions are a cumbersome way to think about measures in dimensions $>1$. Here they make you question something that should be obvious if you think about it the right way.